# Gradle resource file conflict resolution (log4j2.xml)

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2

My main Gradle project A depends on another Gradle project B. Both A and B have a `log4j2.xml` file in

```
src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
```

When I run `./gradlew build`, gradle will pack the `log4j2.xml` file in project B in the final JAR file. Is there a way to specify which `log4j2.xml` file I want to include using Gradle?

I'm using jar plugin

```
jar {
    zip64=true

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your project structure look like? Is it a one root project with two subprojects? Or are you using the other project as a library? Are you using shadow jar plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is one root with multiple sub-projects. I am not using shadow  jar, just jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file name of project A log4j2.xml to log4j2_final.xml and then specify this configuration file explicitly.

See Log4j2 FAQ for more details.

> **How do I specify the configuration file location?**
>
> By default, Log4j looks for a configuration file named log4j2.xml (not log4j.xml) in the classpath.
>
> You can also specify the full path of the configuration file with this system property: -Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
>
> That property can also be included in a classpath resource file named log4j2.component.properties.